# How to make UIAlertController waiting for user interaction?

Tags: swift, ibaction, uialertaction

I have a IBAction button which makes a calculation. In this IBAction, I want to implement an UIAlertController button where the user can press "OK" or "Cancel" to confirm a recalculation.
The Problem is that asap IBAction button is pressed, the calculation is done.

How can I make the function wait for `UIAlertController` response.

```
@IBAction func buttonCalculate(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let startDate = datePickerStart.date
        let endDate = datePikcerEnd.date
        // Calculate DAYS between start and end date
        var diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate).day!
        //calculate ALL between start and end date
        var daily = 6
        diff += 1
        daily = daily*diff
             
        // If "Calculate" button is pressed for recalculationhen 

       
            let emptyDiffCalcDaysLabel = diffCalcDaysLabel.text
            let emptyAmountLabel = allAmount.text
            
            if emptyDiffCalcDaysLabel != "-"  || emptyAmountLabel != "-"
            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Attention", message: "Everything will be recalculated", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) {(ACTION) in print("OK")}
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {(ACTION) in print("Cancel")}
                
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true)
            }
        
                     
          
        //Alert when negative value is calculated
        if diff < 1
        {
            let negativeDaysUIAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Attention", message: "Entered Date is invalid!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            negativeDaysUIAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            self.present(negativeDaysUIAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            // Show "-" instead of negative value
            diffCalcDaysLabel.text = "-"
            allAmount.text = "-"
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is a UIAlert? Do you mean UIAlertController?

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for UIAlertController.
I want the calculation to be done after user selectet "Ok" or "Cancel" Button but asap the IBAction button is pressed, calculation is done before user selected "Ok" or "Cancel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put in the IBAction 'ok' callback, the code to recalculate (or a call the the function that recalculate).

Like that the recalculation is only done when the user click ok.